# Global variables in python/ pytest Selenium Automation

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I am working on automating a test that is dependent on some other tests.

Lets say I have the tests setUp, testA, testB, testC. setUp() sets up the server or resources needed for other tests to start. testA, testB, testC need to wait until setUp is done and only then should start in parallel. My ultimate goal is to parallelize the tests. I was successful in sequential execution of the tests without any parallel execution so that way setUp -> testA -> testB -> testC is the order they are done but in reality testA, testB, testC can run in parallel so running them sequentially is wasting time.

Here is the structure of my project:

test_dummy.py

```
class Values:
       can_continue = False ## This holds the boolean value which I am using for other functions to check if they can continue with their test

class SetUp:
      def test_dummy_setUp():
              ## All the code to setUp the environment
              ##Once above code is done then set the can_continue to true
              Values.can_continue = True
class TestA:
      def test_methodA():
             while Values.can_continue is False:
                     sleep(10)
             ## When the can_continue is changed to True by setUp I want it to break out of loop and continue with execution
             ## Code to be executed
class TestB:
      def test_methodB():
             while Values.can_continue is False:
                     sleep(10)
             ## When the can_continue is changed to True by setUp I want it to break out of loop and continue with execution
             ## Code to be executed
```

When I run the test_dummy using pytest in parallel execution using 3 cores 3 browsers open up for each class (I am using Seleniumbase and using --distload) and as expected setUp proceeds with creating resources while the other two see that can_continue is initially False they go to sleep.
And when the setUp is done creating resources, even though can_continue is set to True inside setUp, it looks like that update is not reflected to other two methods and they are in sleep forever. I can understand that this might be because a new Object is being created for each test class when it is started and the change is not reflected or this might not be the right way at all. I am new to Python and the scope is confusing me right now.

My final goal is to have a variable that is accessible by all three classes SetUp, TestA, TestB and the changes made by any of the classes must also be visible to other classes instantly. What is the best way to achieve this in python?

Thank you

Comment: It's not a good practice to have tests depend on each other. Why not just create a method `setup()` and call it at the start of each test? In NUnit (C#), we have a `OneTimeSetUp` attribute that we can put on a method that causes it to run before all test cases. I would look for a parallel in python... I would be shocked if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I have tried using setup(). Default setup() runs for every test in the module and that's not something what I want. setup() needs to run only once at the beginning and all the tests have to wait for the setup to be done and once done, I want the tests to execute in parallel. I tried everything from fixtures to using globals and variables in different files but no luck so far or maybe I am doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: I guess some of this depends on what setup() actually does but you haven't described it in enough detail. In general, setup() should be run before each test, not once. You can't run all tests in parallel if each instance of a test hasn't run setup(). Best practice is for each test to launch a browser, complete one test, and close the browser. That way each run is as clean as possible and isolated from other tests.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to use pytest fixtures. Set up the tests in fixtures and then pass the fixture to the test. Fixtures will be executed before the tests would.

The code would look something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def setup():
      #setup everything here.

def test_methodA(setup):         
     ## Code to be executed
def test_methodB(setup):         
     ## Code to be executed
```

Edit: Updated the code to simplify it. You don't need to add a lock variable and keep checking it. And, if you are parallelizing test using pytest-xdist, this would work fine. I don't know how SeleniumHub parallelizes tests.

Comment: The setUp and the values doesn't have to be inside a class necessarily. test-dummy_setUp can be independent method and can_continue can be a global variable without them being inside some class. I was just wrapping them inside class to see if it does anything. I am new to python and only been working with it for a week, so if you can tell how you would modify the structure of the code, then I can try to understand from it.